# DataFrame make head on multiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['A', 'B', 12], ['A', 'B', 143], ['C1', 'C1', 11], ['C1', 'C1', 11],['C1', 'C1', 11], ['C3', 'C4', 11]], columns=['first', 'secound', 'data'])

df.set_index(['first', 'secound'], inplace=True)

               data
first secound      
A     B          12
      B         143
C1    C1         11
      C1         11
      C1         11
C3    C4         11
```

I want to get all data of first two index values in the `first` index level.
The desired result is:

```
               data
first secound      
A     B          12
      B         143
C1    C1         11
      C1         11
      C1         11
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
In [9]: df.loc[df.index.get_level_values(0).unique()[:2].tolist()]
Out[9]:
               data
first secound
A     B          12
      B         143
C1    C1         11
      C1         11
      C1         11
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
ix = df.index.levels[0].tolist()[:2]
df.loc[ix, :]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do so:

```
df = df.drop('C3', level='first')
```

Output:

```
               data
first secound      
A     B          12
      B         143
C1    C1         11
      C1         11
      C1         11
```

Comment: Downvoter can you explain me whats wrong, so I can improve the answer?

Comment: It wasn't me... ;) I can only guess that the downvote was caused by the fact that your solution is not flexible - imagine the source DF has more values or that the values in level `first` have different order...

Comment: @MaxU I agree, but imagine that it isnt alphabetically ordered, your solution is not valid anymore too. He gave an example and I gave a possible solution. btw maybe someone else will find the answer useful

Comment: i don't think this question makes much sense if the index values belonging to level `first` have duplicates and aren't sorted... Your solution will not work properly if there are more values in the `first` index level. It'll also not work if the third unique index value is not equal `'C3'`.

Comment: Of course it doesnt work if the third index is not `C3`. As I said it is an answer to his example